# tips "Unhandled exception type xxx" in eclipse

Tags: java, exception

I don't think I understand the try-catch block and throws really.

```
public class TestException {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestException().tt();
    }

    public void tt() {
        try {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

When in Eclipse, there is an error hint about 'Unhandled exception type xxx', and if you run this, you will get an 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Unhandled exception type Exception`

But in Idea, there's no errors. It runs and throws the exception correctly.

In my opnion, the 'e' was not declared as a RuntimeException(althrough it is an RuntimeException), so the tt() method must be declared with throws. But actually it's not. Why?

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your question:

```
public class TestException {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestException().tt();
    }

    public void tt() {
        try {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

If you use **throws**, you tell those who use your function, "My function may **throw** exceptions. You have to handle that."

You should get difference of **throws** and **throw** in this sentence.

If you use try-catch, you handle that exception.

**1)** You should add **throws** keyword like below

```
public class TestException {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestException().tt();
    }

    public void tt() **throws Exception** {
        try {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

}

**2)** **Handle** exception where you use function

```
public class TestException {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            new TestException().tt();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error handled");
        }
    }
    public void tt() throws Exception {
        try {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

In general if you catch an exception you handle it. Like this

```
public class TestException {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestException().tt();
    }

    public void tt() {
        try {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error caught! ")
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
public class TestException {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try  {
          new TestException().tt();
        }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println("Error caught! ")
        }
    }

    public void tt() throws RuntimeException {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

You can also throw other's exception

```
public class TestException {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            new TestException().a();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error handled");
        }
    }

    public void a() throws Exception {
        b();
    }

    public void b() throws Exception {
        c();
    }

    public void c() throws Exception {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the original question? The original code compiles fine in IDEA but not in eclipse.

Comment: @f1sh "I don't think I understand the try-catch block and throws really." He/She said.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to look into 'Checked Exceptions' and 'Unchecked Exceptions'.

Only Checked Exceptions need to be declared in a methods signature, and RuntimeException is an unchecked exception (though you can declare it if you like - it just isn't necessary to compile).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html
The API for java Exception says:
"The class Exception and any subclasses that are not also subclasses of RuntimeException are checked exceptions. Checked exceptions need to be declared in a method or constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or constructor boundary"

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html
The API for java RuntimeException says:
"RuntimeException and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions. Unchecked exceptions do not need to be declared in a method or constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or constructor boundary."

Answer (score 0):

> In my opnion, the 'e' was not declared as a RuntimeException(althrough it is an RuntimeException), so the tt() method must be declared with throws. But actually it's not. Why?

Let's consider what we know:

When using rethrow syntax, the existing exception object (e) is rethrown.

e is an object of class Exception, or one of its subtypes.

RuntimeException is a subtype of exception, and is not compiled time checked, so it's possible the re-thrown object is a non compile time checked object.

The compiler cannot see a place where the code definitely, or even possibly  throws a compile checked exception, and so it makes sense that it does not force those semantics.

For example, if you change your catch to an IOException, the compiler will not allow you to do that without a line in the try which could possibly lead to an IOException.

If you added such a line, then the compiler would recognize that the throw would rethrow a compile time checked exception, and make you catch it again, or mark the function with the appropriate throws clause.

As for eclipse, your code compiles OK in mine with my JDK.